# Multiple HID profile registered with different descriptor

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, bluez

I'm developing a product on a linux system acting as a custom keyboard and can connect via Bluetooth to multiple devices using the BlueZ 5 D-Bus API. So far, I've managed to implement the simultaneous connection capability. However, depending on the device it is connected to, it needs to run a specific HID descriptor for different OS. Using the D-Bus RegisterProfile, I have 2 HID service running at the same time to different paths.

```c
GVariant *profile;
GVariantBuilder profile_builder;
GError *error = NULL;

for(int idx = 0 ; idx < 2 ; idx++)
{
    error = NULL;

    logDebug("Register HID profile\n");

    g_variant_builder_init(&profile_builder, G_VARIANT_TYPE("(osa{sv})"));

    switch(idx)
    {
    case 0: 
        if (!g_variant_is_object_path("/bluetooth/profile/hid1")) {
            logError("Error: object path is not good!\n");
            return -1;
        }  
        g_variant_builder_add (&profile_builder, "o", "/bluetooth/profile/hid1");
        break;
    case 1: 
        if (!g_variant_is_object_path("/bluetooth/profile/hid2")) {
            logError("Error: object path is not good!\n");
            return -1;
        }  
        g_variant_builder_add (&profile_builder, "o", "/bluetooth/profile/hid2");
        break;
    default:
        logError("Wrong index for service record register\n");
        return -1;
        break;
    }

    g_variant_builder_add (&profile_builder, "s", HID_PROFILE_UUID);

    g_variant_builder_open(&profile_builder, G_VARIANT_TYPE("a{sv}"));

    // SERVICE
    g_variant_builder_open(&profile_builder, G_VARIANT_TYPE("{sv}"));
    g_variant_builder_add (&profile_builder, "s", "Service");
    g_variant_builder_add (&profile_builder, "v", g_variant_new_string(HID_PROFILE_UUID));
    g_variant_builder_close(&profile_builder);

    // NAME
    g_variant_builder_open(&profile_builder, G_VARIANT_TYPE("{sv}"));
    g_variant_builder_add (&profile_builder, "s", "Name");
    g_variant_builder_add (&profile_builder, "v", g_variant_new_string("HID"));
    g_variant_builder_close(&profile_builder);

    // Autoconnect
    g_variant_builder_open(&profile_builder, G_VARIANT_TYPE("{sv}"));
    g_variant_builder_add (&profile_builder, "s", "AutoConnect");
    g_variant_builder_add (&profile_builder, "v", g_variant_new_boolean(true));
    g_variant_builder_close(&profile_builder);

    // SERVICE RECORD
    g_variant_builder_open(&profile_builder, G_VARIANT_TYPE("{sv}"));
    g_variant_builder_add (&profile_builder, "s", "ServiceRecord");
    switch(idx)
    {
    case 0: 
        g_variant_builder_add (&profile_builder, "v", g_variant_new_string(SERVICE_RECORD_HW1));
        break;
    case 1:
        g_variant_builder_add (&profile_builder, "v", g_variant_new_string(SERVICE_RECORD_HW2));
        break;
    default:
        logError("Wrong index for service record register\n");
        break;
    }
    g_variant_builder_close(&profile_builder);

    // ROLE
    g_variant_builder_open(&profile_builder, G_VARIANT_TYPE("{sv}"));
    g_variant_builder_add (&profile_builder, "s", "Role");
    g_variant_builder_add (&profile_builder, "v", g_variant_new_string("server"));
    g_variant_builder_close(&profile_builder);

    g_variant_builder_close(&profile_builder);
    profile = g_variant_builder_end(&profile_builder);

    g_dbus_proxy_call_sync (proxy,
        "RegisterProfile",
        profile,
        G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
        -1,
        NULL,
        &error);

    if(error != NULL)
    {
        logError("Unable to register profile to bluez through dbus. Be sure that bluetoothd deamon is running\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

When running `sdptool browse local`, there are 2 HID services displayed.

However, when I connect the custom keyboard to different devices, it seems that only the first HID descriptor **/bluetooth/profile/hid1** is used. When I change the order of the HID service registered, **/bluetooth/profile/hid2** becomes the HID in use. What I'd like to know is how can I implement a way to run a certain HID descriptor depending on the device it is connected to? Also, in this current case with multiple HID profile registered, how does a device choose which service to connect to?